# reverse geocode a set of co-ordinates

Tags: php, javascript, html, reverse-geocoding

I have sets of co-ordinates in the following format

> (-33.9,18.6)

How do I go about getting the name of the nearest town or Country for those co-ords? I'm guessing it will involve Javascript, but am happy to also use PHP if appropriate?

EDIT: Am trying the [Google Reverse Geocoder](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#ReverseGeocoding) but having trouble with it. The following code is pretty identical to one of their examples but doesn't seem to be running at all... any ideas why?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function reverseGeocode(lat,lon){

                var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
                var latlng = new GLatLng(lat, lon);
                geocoder.getLocations(latlng, function(addresses) {
                    alert(addresses);
                });

            }
        </script>
```

Comment: You *are* calling the function, right?

Comment: yep, if I put an alert("test") on the first line of the function it fires off once, but if I put it after the var geocoder line it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok managed to get it working, so here's what I did:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=INSERTAPIKEYHERE" type="text/javascript"></script>
function reverseGeocode(latitude,longitude){

            var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
            var latlng = new GLatLng(latitude, longitude);

            geocoder.getLocations(latlng, function(addresses) {
                var address = addresses.Placemark[0].address;
                var country = addresses.Placemark[0].AddressDetails.Country.CountryName;
                var locality = addresses.Placemark[0].AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.SubAdministrativeArea.Locality.LocalityName;

                alert(address);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

google has a webservice you can call to do (reverse) geocoding, which is much more lightweight then using the full javascript api.

an example with v2: http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=51,4&sensor=false&output=json&key=insert_your_api_key_here&callback=parseme

and with v3: 
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=51,4&sensor=false&callback=parseme

in both cases you get a json response (javascript object), the difference being that in the now deprecated v2 you need to provide you api key and you can use a callback (for cross site ajax goodness) which for crying out loud [isn't supported in v3 any more](http://blog.futtta.be/2010/04/09/no-more-jsonp-for-google-geocoding-webservice/) (but you don't need an api key any more).

Comment: Thanks, cold you maybe show me some sample code for using the webservice? I'm not sure how to go about it

Comment: my still ongoing experiment lives at http://futtta.be/checkRoam/ 

It tries to find your coordinates (geolocation browser, html5) and uses those to get country code. Feel free to view source and copy/ paste.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps API has a javascript example.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: have you any experience with it? I'm trying the following but to no avail
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     function reverseGeocode(lat,lon){
     
     var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
     var latlng = new GLatLng(lat, lon);
     geocoder.getLocations(latlng, function(addresses) {
      alert(addresses);
     });
     
     }
   </script>

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered for their API key?

Also are there any specific error messages?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the google api successfully to get the user's current location, but for some reason can't get reverse geolocation